# A new session is being created in every request on web api

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a ASPN.NET WEB API 1(with .NET framework 4.0) application with AngularJS, and I am using session to authenticate the users(I know it should be stateless, but for legacy purpose I am using session). In my application, in every request I make to my WEB API it creates a new session, even when I set values to my session.

The sessions is allowed in my appication through this code in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors-origins"];
            bool hasSlash = origins.Substring(origins.Length - 1, 1) == "/";
            if (hasSlash)
                origins = origins.Substring(0, origins.Length - 1);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origins);
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                             "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                             "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }

        protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            if (IsWebApiRequest())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
            }
        }
```

Then I set values to my session in my controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(LoginViewModel model)
    {
    // SOME BUSINESS LOGIC HERE...

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.User, false);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["usuario"] = model.User;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "User successfylly logged in!");
    }
```

But when I do another request to my application to access another method in controller, it throws me an error because session is null, like in this method:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var userName = HttpContext.Current.Session["usuario"];

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, userName);
    }
```

In my web.config, session is configured like this:

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" >
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

PS: It does not work on Chrome, but on IE it works, and doing request directly on postman it also works.

Comment: when you build an API, each request is separate and has no connection whatsoever to any previous or future request. You're not building a web application here. If you want to know who is sending the request then look into an authentication mechanism, like oauth or whatever else you think is appropriate. Just don't treat  an api like a web app, there is no legacy excuse here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was missing this line in my `Application_BeginRequest`

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

And in every request on AngularJS I should pass withCredentials parameter as true. To achieve that, I put this line on my config file in AngularJS:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```